# Allow either exactly two dots or none in date regex

Tags: regex, date

I have the following regex, which should match dates in german format (dd.mm.yyyy)

`^((0(?!0))?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.((0(?!0))?[1-9]|1[0-2])\.([12][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2})$/gm`

The dots should be optional, but the user should either enter both or none.

So:

```
01.01.2000 => ok
01012000 => ok
01.012000 => nok
0101.2000 => nok
```

I tried fiddling around with lookaround expressions, but I didn't come to a working solution.

Comment: Try using an alternation and match the same part without the dots, or a capturing group matching an optional dot with a backreference. Using your multiple capturing groups it would be group 3 `^((0(?!0))?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\.?)((0(?!0))?[1-9]|1[0-2])\3([12][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2})$`  https://regex101.com/r/bkL8cu/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture the dot in a group and make it optional. To match the second dot, you could use a backreference to what is captured in the group with the first optional dot.

Updating the pattern, the backreference would be group 3:

```
^((0(?!0))?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\.?)((0(?!0))?[1-9]|1[0-2])\3([12][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2})$
                                 ^^^^^                       ^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkL8cu/1)

Note that there are a lot of capturing groups. If you don't need them in after processing, you could also use non capturing groups instead `(?:`

With only a single capturing group for the backreference, the pattern could look like:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\.?)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\1(?:[12][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M2Sv9I/1)

This part `^((0(?!0))?[1-9]` will not match `00` as the character class `[1-9]` does not match a zero.

If you want to match an optional zero, you could use `0?[1-9]`

Comment: thanks, that works fine and the explanation was great!
One more issue I didn't mention in the original question, though:
leading zeroes for numbers < 10 are mandatory when dots are not provided.

01012000 => ok
112000 => nok, since 11111 could be 1.11.11 or 11.1.11 

Could that be done within the regex, or would it be simpler to split the two conditions in two regexes?

Comment: In that case you could use an alternation `|` to match either the version with or without the dots https://regex101.com/r/d7smNB/1

Comment: I got it :)
I use a positive lookahead for a length of 6-10 chars in the main capture group
`^(?=.{6,10}$)(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\.?)(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\2([12][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2})$`